# How to toggle the google-maps autocomplete on and off?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm instantiating an autocomplete input for Google Maps API (level 3), like so:

```
var input = document.getElementById('szukanyAdres');
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

How to turn the autocompletion functionality on and off at runtime?

Comment: I don't understand, you don't want to use autocomplete on your site? So, why not just remove the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two elements related to the autocomplete

1. the input-element
2. a div that contains the list-entries. this div will be appended to the body and has the class "pac-container"

So what you can do: show or hide both elements by modifying their display-style.

---

When it's not possible to hide the input you may replace the input with a clone of the input, this will remove the autocomplete-functionality.

```
inputObject.parentNode.replaceChild(inputObject.cloneNode(true),input);
```

To restore the autocomplete do again what you want to do.

Comment: added another suggestion above

Answer (score 18):

To remove all listeners added to autocomplete.

```
autocomplete.unbindAll();
```

To remove all listeners added to input element.

```
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(input);
```

See https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3429

Comment: Holy crap, yes thank you!  Spent hours trying to toggle between google places and another API in the event of multiple failed inputs, and this actually solved the problem.  After disabling Places, our other service was showing suggestions, but the keydown was being hanlded by google populating the input with suggestions despite the other events being disabled and the container hidden.

Answer (score 11):

The solution of Dr.Molle doesn't work for me.

The solution I found is to clearListener and remove pac-container:

```
var autocomplete;
var autocompleteListener;
function disableGoogleAutocomplete() {
    if (autocomplete !== undefined) {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(autocompleteListener);
            google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(autocomplete);
            $(".pac-container").remove();

            console.log('disable autocomplete to GOOGLE');
     }
}
function enableGoogleAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#inputDiv input")[0], options);
    autocompleteListener = google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() { ... }
    console.log('set autocomplete to GOOGLE');
}
```

Now I can switch on/off google places Autocomplete.

Comment: Are you sure this is functionally disabling the autocomplete? Visually it works, but when I comment out $('.pac-container').remove() the listener / autocomplete is still active.

Comment: Yes, I use this to switch between Google maps autocomplete and my own data.

Comment: Why do you use `google.maps.event.removeListener` here? You are using `google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners` and it's enough.

Comment: I didn't remember why, but I think that with this method the autocomplete was not disable. Need to be test.

Comment: It didn't disable it totally: there is still events on press key up and key down

Answer (score 0):

If anything written here does not work for you, you can try to just hide it.
The field with places appearing while typing is in css class .pac-container, so just declare it in css display: none. Then it will not appear during typing in searchbox. Actually it is not the way to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide it with JQuery:

```
$(".pac-container").hide(); //hide autocomplete
```

Comment: This will not work everytime since google's javascript will show it again, even if you will change or remove the classes of the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem as well (in my app I wanted to run the google's autocomplete only when user typed at least 4 digits into my input field - I am using my custom smart search when typed string has less than 4 digits).

In my case above solutions didn't work either, so my workaround is:

1. Set opacity: 0 to the $('.pac-container') when you need.
2. Optionally set also low z-index if needed.