# How to disable google maps autocomplete feature from textbox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I am adding an autocomplete to a text box like this.

```
        input = dom.byId("searchBox");
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

How can I disable autocomplete on this text box.

Comment: Did you make a mistake in your question? Your question currently is: _"I'm adding feature A, how do I remove feature A?"_

Comment: @youtubeline: Why you are adding it in the first place. If you don't want it. Do you want to use your own autocomplete logic?

Comment: I want to use a textbox (searchBox) to search Google places and to search something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to toggle the google-maps autocomplete on and off?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828856/how-to-toggle-the-google-maps-autocomplete-on-and-off)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(input);
```