# How to add and remove part of javascript code through a javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am implementing the address autocomplete functionality in **onkeyup()** event of the asp.net textbox.

I want the autocomplete functionality to kick in only after the user enters a minimum of 7 characters.

It works fine for the first time. However once the user clears the input box, then the autocomplete works even when a single character is entered.

This is because the javascript code which implements it is already there. It will work as desired again after a page reload.

Is there anyway to make it work without a page reload.

Following is my code:

```
<asp:textbox id="txtAddressInput" runat="server" autocomplete="false" onkeyup="input_onchange(this)"></asp:textbox>
<script>
        function input_onchange(me) {
                if (me.value.length > 7) {
                autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                (document.getElementById('txtAddress')),
                { types: ['geocode'] });
        }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('txtAddress'), 'keydown', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13 && $('.pac-container:visible').length) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
        });
    }
<script>
```

Comment: You probably need to do something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/22862011/14104

Comment: Thanks. That helped!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code it looks like you just need an `else` statement clearing the autocomplete object.  Something like

```
else if (me.value.length < 7 && autocomplete != null) {
    autocomplete = null;
}
```

Also your if statement will require a minimum of 8 characters, not 7 (you're using `>` instead `>=`)